# Computer stopped booting after I tried to allocate a drive to unallocated space

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, multi-boot

I installed Ubuntu on my Windows 7 yesterday and after that I booted to Windows. After that as I saw an unallocated space while installing Ubuntu, I tried to allocate that unallocated space to make it a drive. So I went to Disk Partition and tried to make a new volume. When I completed the steps, it had thrown an error that `this drive letter can not be used as it is already used` or  something error like this, and it did not format that drive. After realizing  that it might be used for that `reserved space` for `boot` option for Windows, I tried to give it another letter name and it formatted well and the new drive was created.

But the problem after that is that now I can not boot in, neither in Ubuntu nor in Windows. The monitor says `no signal detected`.

It looks like there is no hardware problem as I can boot in Ubuntu by a usb stick .

So what could be the problem?

Can this be something related to boot options, grub menu, etc.?